# Timeout using Balancer, IHS, WebSphere and Birt

Tags: apache, websphere, load-balancing, birt, mod-proxy-balancer

I have an application that generates a report that process in more than 30min and I receive a timeout error. If I generate a report and it lasts less then 20 min, it works. My environment works as follow:

```
   Balancer https://www.example.com/
   /   \
IHS1   IHS2  redirect IHS:443 to WAS:9081 (WEB) and WAS:9082 (REPORT)
 /        \
WAS1     WAS2 WAS:WEB and WAS:REPORT
\         /
    DB
```

When I change my application to return data to WAS or IHS it works. If I return to balancer I receive a timeout.
Here is my configutation on IHS:

```
ServerName   example.com
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch ^/$ https://example.com/example/

SSLEnable
SSLProtocolDisable    SSLv2
SSLProtocolDisable    SSLv3
SSLCipherSpec         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
SSLCipherSpec         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
SSLCipherSpec         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
SSLCipherSpec         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
SSLCipherSpec         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
SSLCipherSpec         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
SSLClientAuth         none
SSLServerCert         example-ssl
KeyFile               /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/ssl/example.kdb
SSLStashfile          /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/ssl/example.sth

ProxyPass           /example-rel/                             http://10.10.0.3:9082/example-rel/ connectiontimeout=7200 timeout=7200
ProxyPassReverse    /example-rel/                             http://10.10.0.3:9082/example-rel/

ProxyPass          /example/                              http://10.10.0.2:9081/example/ connectiontimeout=7200 timeout=7200
ProxyPassReverse   /example/                              http://10.10.0.2:9081/example/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath  /    /example/

ErrorLog     logs/ihs-443-example-error_log
CustomLog    logs/ihs-443-example-access_log  common_ssl
```

I set timeout on webcontainer/ejb container/tranaction manager to 7200 and session management invalidationTimeout 120 min. I also set the HttpInboundPersistReadTimeout on the custom properties on WAS.

Did I forget to increase the timeout somewhere?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are saying you can get a report running for more than 30 minutes if you are accessing WAS or IHS. If that is the case it sounds like your load balancer have a timeout, possibly a timeout for an idle connection. If the load balancer doesn't see any traffic on the open connection for some time it will disconnect. It could also be some other network component along the way such as a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

If using one of the load balancers that ships with WAS, look at the staletimeout setting.